# Changing color of existing NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, catextlayer

I'm trying to create a category to change the color of an existing NSAttributedString that is rendered in a CATextLayer.  Here's the category implementation

```
@implementation NSAttributedString (_additions)

-(NSAttributedString*)attributedStringWithColor:(UIColor*)color{

    NSMutableAttributedString* mutableSelf = [self mutableCopy];

    [mutableSelf addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:NSMakeRange(0, mutableSelf.length)];

    return [mutableSelf attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, mutableSelf.length)];

}
@end
```

The CATextLayer is in a subclass of CAShapeLayer.  I should also mention that the CATextLayer does render with the correct attributes, EXCEPT the color.

```
// in .m

// class continuation:
    @interface ONCShapeLayerSubclass()
    {
        CATextLayer* textLayer;    
    }
    @end

@implementation
//...

-(void)update{

    // method that initializes the catextlayer 
    //...

    if(!textLayer){
        textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
        textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
        textLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        textLayer.foregroundColor = [kDefaultLineColor CGColor];
        [self addSublayer:textLayer];
    }

    textLayer.string = //// a method that returns an attributed string from a database

   //...

    [self updateColor];
} 


-(void)updateColor{

     if(textLayer)textLayer.string = [textLayer.string attributedStringWithColor:kDefaultLineColor];
}

@end
```

The string shows up attributed EXCEPT for the color.  And then I get a whole bunch of errors:

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: Show the code where you are _calling_ `attributedStringWithColor:`. _That_ is where the problem is - not in the code you have shown.

Comment: Are you sure `textLayer.string` is an attributed string? It might be an `NSString`. It could also be `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, I did check that it wasn't nil by changing to if(textLayer.string)...

Comment: And I've checked that the strings are attributed.

Comment: Are you really showing us the actual code where the problem actually occurs? Or are you just typing some stuff that is kind of like it?

Comment: It's actual code, but its part of a big project, so I am necessarily leaving out other things that should not be relevant.  I will update to include more context.

Comment: Take a look at this http://cocoafactory.com/blog/2012/10/29/how-to-use-custom-nsattributedstring-attributes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is a bug with CATextLayer, and not with my code.  It works correctly for text displayed in UILabels, just not in CATextLayers.